# transform view, keep subview size

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, cgaffinetransform

I have a view, which the user can *scale* and *rotate* through `UIGestureRecognizer`. This view contains two views:

```
 superview
  - content
  - button
```

The `content` should be scaled and rotated, and the `button` should keep it's size and position. 
I'am scaling and rotating the views with help of `CGAffineTransform` and `UIGestureRecognizer`.

How can I achieve this?

I've tried:

- to scale/rotate the `superview` and reset the `button` transform and position. No success.
- to scale/rotate the `content` and try to set the `content.frame.size` to the `superview`. No success. (Although I think this has to work somehow).
- and some obscure bad things, which are not worth to mention.

**Edit:**

The code which handles the rotating and scaling:

```
if ([recognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(rotation)]) {
    CGFloat rotation = 0.0f - (self.lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) recognizer rotation]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.content.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, rotation);
    self.content.transform = newTransform;

    self.lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) recognizer rotation];

} else if ([recognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    CGFloat scale = 1.0f - (self.lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) recognizer scale]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.content.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);
    self.content.transform = newTransform;

    self.lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) recognizer scale];
}
```

Just basic scaling and rotating, nothing fancy.

Comment: Using bullet item two: after scaling/rotating the content, why are you changing the `content.frame.size`?  Note that the `content.frame` is the smallest rectangle that encloses the view, so it's tricky to use on a view that's been rotated.  You can use the `center` and `bounds` properties to move and scale the view, and use the `transform` to rotate the view around its center.

Comment: If I scale the `content` the `bounds` doesn't change. I set just the `size`, because the `content` will have different `x` and `y` coordinates, than the `superview`. The `superview` can be moved around in it's parent view.
The scaling and resizing itself is done by using `CGAffineTransform`.

Comment: Is the `content` a single view with no subviews, or is it multiple views and/or subviews?

Comment: `content` is just a single `UIImageView`.

Comment: So my suggestion is to use `bounds.size` to scale the view, use `transform` _only_ for rotation, and use the `center` property to position the view properly in the `superview`.

Comment: Works great, for resizing only the content. Any idead how to properly resize the superview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual solution:

```
if ([recognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(rotation)]) {
    CGFloat rotation = 0.0f - (self.lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) recognizer rotation]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, rotation);
    self.transform = newTransform;

    self.lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) recognizer rotation];

} else if ([recognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    CGFloat scale = 1.0f - (self.lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) recognizer scale]);

    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    bounds.size.width *= scale;
    bounds.size.height *= scale;
    self.bounds = bounds;

    self.lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *) recognizer scale];
}
```